# backtracking - solution hint for generating schedule

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

There are 3 hours of math, 2 of phisics and 3 of informatics. I need to generate all possible schedules so that a day must have at least 1 hour of these subjects and at maximum 3 of these (it could be math-math-math or math-physics-informatics)

The schedule is for 5 days.
So I came up with the following solution:

Let generate(k, o) be the 'generator' function for k-th day with o hours, o between 1 and 3

For every day k and hour o pick a subject that is still in our left. I keep track of it by having an array `counter[i] = TakenCount`, where i is 1, 2, 3 corresponding to math, physics and informatics, and TakenCount means how many hours of that subject I used.

And for the configuration I use a matrix `v[k][o]` which gives me the configuration for day k, with hours o

This is the code I've tried so far

```
h = ['', 'm', 'f', 'i']
counter = [0, 0, 0, 0]
limit = [0, 3, 2, 3]
v = [['' for x in range(4)] for x in range(6)]

def generate(k, o):
  if k == 6:
    if counter[1] == limit[1] and counter[2] == limit[2] and counter[3] == limit[3]:
      showConfig()
  else:
    for i in range(1, 4, 1):
      if counter[i] != limit[i]:
        v[k][o] = h[i]
        counter[i] += 1

        generate(k + 1, 1)
        generate(k + 1, 2)
        generate(k + 1, 3)

        v[k][o] = ''
        counter[i] -= 1

def showConfig():
  print '-- Configuration --'
  print counter

  for i in range(1, 6, 1):
    print 'Day ', i,
    success = False

    for j in range(1, 4, 1):
      print v[i][j],

  print '-- End --'

generate(1, 1)
generate(1, 2)
generate(1, 3)
```

It's written in Python but I think that's not a problem, because it's pretty easy to read

The problem here is I never get to have hours inside `v[i][2]` and `v[i][3]`, only for `v[i][1]`, and the condition

```
counter[1] == 3, counter[2] == 2 and counter[3] == 3
```

never gets true and I do not know why.

Also after I generate for the following day, that is `k + 1`, with hours 1, 2 and 3, I need to reset current `v[k][o] to` '' and `counter[i]` to `counter[i] - 1`

This is not a homework or something simillar. I'm asking if the solution is good and if it is, then what I did wrong in my code? Because I can't seem to find out

Output example:

```
( (m), (m, f), (m, f, i), (i), (i) )
...
( (m, i), (f), (i), (m, f, i), (m) )
( (m, f), (i), (i), (m, f, i), (m) )
```

where m is math, f is physics and i informatics, and each paranthesis is a DAY in a WEEK, so 5 days in 1 Week

Comment: I have no knowledge about python, but seems count[1]+count[2]+count[3]==5 when k==6. Try to debug it. Print counter when k==6.

Comment: It has to be 3+3+2=8 always. I know there is some bug there but I do not know where

Comment: Just look at your else part in generate method. Your code attempt to assign 1 hour of subject on any single day only, that's why count[1]+count[2]+count[3]==5 when k==6.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
from itertools import permutations
def possible_permutations(*args):
    length_args = len(args)
    args_list, permutations_list = [], []
    for arg in args:
        args_list.append(arg)
        permutations_list.append(tuple(permutations(args_list)))
    # Clean ugly list of touples of touples into a list of touples.
    perms = []
    for perm in permutations_list:
        for p in perm:
            perms.append(p)
    return perms

def schedules(days, *classes):
    possible_perms = possible_permutations(*classes)
    for perm in permutations(possible_perms, days):
        print(perm)
schedules(5, 'math', 'science', 'english')
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

It is not entirly clear to me what your asking, but I belive this solves your question.

```
from itertools import permutations

CLASSES = {'math':3, 'physics':2, 'informatics':3}
def possible_schedules(**classes_hours):
    k, v = [k for k, v in classes_hours.items()], [v for k, v in classes_hours.items()]
    k_perms, v_perms = permutations(k), permutations(v)
    perms = zip(k_perms, v_perms)
    for k_perm, v_perm in perms:
        perm = tuple(zip(k_perm, v_perm))
        print(perm)

possible_schedules(**CLASSES)
```

Output:

```
(('physics', 2), ('math', 3), ('informatics', 3))
(('physics', 2), ('informatics', 3), ('math', 3))
(('math', 3), ('physics', 2), ('informatics', 3))
(('math', 3), ('informatics', 3), ('physics', 2))
(('informatics', 3), ('physics', 2), ('math', 3))
(('informatics', 3), ('math', 3), ('physics', 2))
```

Comment: I need all possible combinations to generate schedule for 5 days, where each day must have at least one hour of Math/Phisics/Informatics and at maximum 3 of these. All combinations. What you did here is pure permutations.

Comment: Sample output: ( (m), (m, f), (m, f, i), (i), (i) - one combination .. etc - where m is math, f is physics etc ) ALSO: I need to use all 3 math/2 physics/3 info hours, not only some of them

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by one hour of each, as they are all over one hour.

Comment: I added a sample output and some comments on it. Tell me now if you understand

Comment: It's ok now as it generates all possible combinations, but I said there is a limitation. Those disciplines cannot be used more than 3, 2, respectively 3 times in a week schedule. So I cannot have math more than 3 times, science more than 2 times or english more than 3 times. This limitation I don't think you can introduce it in your code, as it gets pretty messy, that's why I used the manual backtracking code, not relying on pure permutations

Comment: If you do really want to help me, please look on my code. Maybe you'll spot something that I didn't see. I don't think it's possible to solve the problem the way you tried